# Can't figure out whether this if statement is wrong or the clearInterval

Tags: javascript, if-statement, clearinterval

Was playing around with a few tutorials I found online which then I came across to this, not sure how why my if statement won't work

```js
var myVar;
var myNum;
myNum = 0;

function alertFunc() {
  myNum = myNum + 1;
  console.log("Hello! " + myNum);
}

function myFunction() {

  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 1000);

  if (myNum == 3) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}

console.log(myFunction());
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? and what is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to clear the interval.

```
function myFunction() {

  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 1000);

  if (myNum == 3) {  // this if blocktrue will never happen
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}
```

Reason: The above if block true will never happen as it is called **once** when myNum is 1.

So you need to rewrite the check in the interval function as written below.

```js
var myVar;
var myNum;
myNum=0;

function alertFunc() {
  myNum=myNum+1;
  console.log("Hello! " + myNum);
  if (myNum==3){ //when myNum is 3 clear the timer interval.
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }

}

function myFunction() {

  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 1000);

}


console.log(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because it is not calling myFunction() again again it only checks the if condition first time which is 0

```js
var myVar;
var myNum;
myNum = 3;

function alertFunc() {
  myNum = myNum + 1;
  console.log("Hello! " + myNum);
  console.log(typeof myNum);
}

function myFunction() {

  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 1000);

  if (myNum == 3) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  }
}

console.log(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check the condition

```
if (myNum == 3) {
   clearInterval(myVar);
}
```

in your `alertFunc()` since it is executed every interval. The current place of your if will never be true because it runs only once after you set the interval, which `myNum` is 0 as you initialized it.

Here is what you want it to be.

```js
var myVar;
var myNum;
myNum = 0;

function alertFunc() {
  if (myNum == 3) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
  } else {
    myNum = myNum + 1;
    console.log("Hello! " + myNum);
  }
}

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setInterval(alertFunc, 1000);
}

console.log(myFunction());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `clearInterval` in  `alertFunc` like bellow

```
function alertFunc() {
   myNum = myNum + 1;
  console.log("Hello! " + myNum);
   if (myNum == 3) {
       clearInterval(myVar);
   }
 }
```

from `myFunction` you are calling `alertFunc` with `setInterval` so code does not execute bellow